# Inconsistent accessibility error (c#)

Tags: c#

I've been a vb developer for years but *Just* started using c#.

I'm not sure what this error means or how to fix it. All my previous searches have returned nothing that helps me.  Can you guys help with this ?

Here's the error:

Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ServeArticle.ReturnStyle' is less accessible than method 'ServeArticle.DisplayArticle(int, string, ServeArticle.ReturnStyle)'

Here's my code:

```
public partial class ServeArticle : BaseWebPage
{

    protected mArticle objArticle;
    protected string strHTML;

    enum ReturnStyle:int
    {
        XML_SingleArticle = 4,
        XML_MultiArticle = 5
    };


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DisplayArticle(123, 'p123', (ReturnStyle)intReturnStyle);
        }

    }


    protected void DisplayArticle(int intPublisherID, string strPublisherKey, ReturnStyle intReturnStyle)
    {
        try
        {.....
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ReturnStyle` enum is `private`, but it must be `protected` or `public` because `DisplayArticle` method is `protected`. It must be *at least* as accessible as your method.

Answer (score 1):

The `enum ReturnStyle` is `private` by default, so you can't use it as parameter to the `DisplayArticle` method. Solution: use `public` or `protected` modifiers ;)

Comment: Thank you mate. swapping from VB to C# without you guys would be a damn sight harder.

Answer (score 1):

The enum `ReturnStyle` without any access modifier is private (this is the default access modifier), hence you get this error because `DispalyArticle` is protected. Any class can inherit from `ServeArticle` and by doing that will have access to `DisplayArticle()` which has  `ReturnStyle` as a paramter.

Comment: Cheers Adrian, a solution and a very good explanation as to why is it's happening. Thanks a lot.